# Setting shell variable before command gives 'command not found'

Tags: shell-script, shell, variable

I am trying to set a shell variable and pass it into a command as part of a Shell script with the following code:

```
SLS_DEBUG_TEXT=""
if [ "$ENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING" = "true" ]; then
  SLS_DEBUG_TEXT="SLS_DEBUG=* "
fi

$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT sls create_domain -v $AWS_PROFILE_FLAG --stage $STAGE // gives error
#SLS_DEBUG=* sls create_domain -v $AWS_PROFILE_FLAG --stage $STAGE // works correctly
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
./sls-deploy.sh: line 110: SLS_DEBUG_TEXT: command not found
```

The `if` statement is mostly irrelevant but I want to show that this variable needs to be set conditionally (i.e. I don't always want the debug logging enabled). The last line in the code snippet (which is commented out) is what the command should look like if debug logging is enabled and this works correctly.

I have found a few previous posts on here and Stack Overflow where the issue was due to spaces between the equals sign when setting a variable ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340412/executing-this-shell-script-gives-command-not-found-error)) but I don't *think* I've fallen into that trap here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT` is expanded too late, after the stage where the shell would otherwise treat its value as an assignment.  The variable's value is therefore instead treated as a command.

What you could do instead is to use `env`:

```sh
SLS_DEBUG_TEXT='SLS_DEBUG=*'
env "$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT" sls create_domain -v "$AWS_PROFILE_FLAG" --stage "$STAGE"
```

Note the quoting around *every single variable expansion*.

If `SLS_DEBUG_TEXT` may be empty or unset, the above would generate an error since `env` would try to execute a command with no name.

To work around that, you may instead use

```sh
SLS_DEBUG_TEXT='SLS_DEBUG=*'
env ${SLS_DEBUG_TEXT:+"$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT"} sls create_domain -v "$AWS_PROFILE_FLAG" --stage "$STAGE"
```

The `${SLS_DEBUG_TEXT:+"$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT"}` would expand to `"$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT"` if that variable is set and non-empty.  Otherwise it would expand to nothing (not even an empty string, which would be the case with `"$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT"`).

Note too that if you have `SLS_DEBUG_TEXT='SLS_DEBUG=* '` (as in your code), the space after the `*` would become part of the value of `SLS_DEBUG` in the `sls` process' environment.  I don't know if this is intended or not.

---

I'm also noticing that the error message that you quote says

```
./sls-deploy.sh: line 110: SLS_DEBUG_TEXT: command not found
```

To me, this indicates that you are using the variable's name without `$` in front of it at some point in the script. This may be totally unrelated to the main issue that you had.  The code that you *show* would instead cause the error

```
./sls-deploy.sh: line NNN: SLS_DEBUG=*: command not found
```

Comment: What is the impact of using `env`? Does that set it just for the command I'm running or globally? This script calls Serverless a few times and I don't want to enable debug logging on them all.

Comment: @StuartLeyland-Cole The `env` utility sets the value in its own environment, and then invokes the given command (`sls`) with the modified environment.  The utility can not set the environment variable for the current shell. I.e., the variable will not be set "globally".

Comment: `env` works great if `SLS_DEBUG_TEXT` is set to `SLS_DEBUG=*` but when it isn't I get `env: : No such file or directory`. Note that `SLS_DEBUG_TEXT` is only set if debug logging is enabled. Is there a way to make `env` work in this situation?

Comment: @StuartLeyland-Cole Yes, use `env ${SLS_DEBUG_TEXT:+"$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT"} sls ...` I will add this to the answer with an explanation.

Comment: There is a lot of helpful information in this answer so I'm marking it as the accepted answer even though I didn't exactly use your answer! In fact I created a function that checks the `ENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING` variable as suggested in [Michael Homer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538682/184722) as I repeat this logic several times. The text expansion, `${a:+"$a"}, in particular was very useful. Thanks for all your clarifications and edits too.

Answer (score 4):

The [shell grammar recognises assignment words at the lexing stage](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02), long before parameter expansion occurs. Although you can have a parameter expand to a *command*, you can't have one expand to an assignment — it's just treated as a command at that point, even though it's textually the same (it's like you wrote `"SLS_DEBUG=*" sls ...`).

This is an oddity of the shell command language parsing and evaluation. Certain kinds of behaviour are determined lexically when the code is first read in, and those behaviours can never be recovered later on even though things generally *appear* to work by textual substitution.

You *can* use `SLS_DEBUG_TEXT="eval SLS_DEBUG='*' "` and it will work, albeit with potential problems if the remainder of the command can ever have any shell metacharacters in it. Another option is to conditionally define a function instead:

```
sls_debug() { :; }
if [ "$ENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING" = "true" ]; then
    sls_debug() {
        SLS_DEBUG='*' "$@"
    }
fi
sls_debug sls create_domain ...
```

Alternatively (and perhaps clearer) a function that just checks `$ENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING` internally would work as well, or `env "$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT" ...` or `eval "$SLS_DEBUG_TEXT" ...` will also be explicit.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of creating a function which checks the `ENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING` variable and adds the `SLS_DEBUG=*` text if required. This was the better solution specifically for me as I am making multiple calls to Serverless. I will add my function as a separate answer just for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness this is how I ended up solving my issue which was a combination of [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538681/184722) and [Michael Homer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538682/184722).

```
function executeServerlessCommand() {
  if [ "$ENABLE_SLS_DEBUG_LOGGING" = "true" ]; then
    SLS_DEBUG='*' "$@"
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}

executeServerlessCommand sls create_domain -v ${AWS_PROFILE_FLAG:+"$AWS_PROFILE_FLAG"} --stage "$STAGE"
```

Some points of note:

1. I created a function which takes the command to run, checks the `ENABLE_SLS_DEBUG_LOGGING` variable and prepends `SLS_DEBUG=*` to the command if true, otherwise executes the provided command
2. I used the `${a:+"$a"}` syntax for the `AWS_PROFILE_FLAG` variable which only adds the variable value if set. Previously this variable was not quoted properly.